# Why git rebase creates conflicts, but git rebase -i does not?

Tags: git, merge, conflict, rebase

I occasionally have strange conflicts when rebasing feature branch onto master branch. I've changed just some lines in files, but conflict message shows that those files are deleted, which is not correct.

Recently I got hint from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951108/git-rebase-master-feature-gives-rename-delete-conflict-git-rebase-i-master-f) and tried rebasing using `git rebase -i` and picking all the commits. Using that command I managed to rebase without those strange conflicts.

I would like to understand, why plain `rebase` did not work, but `rebase -i` did. Any clues?

I'm using git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0

Comment: So what's the problem? Performing the rounds of conflict resolution when rebasing? Fixing the commits when rebasing is a common and perfectly feasible task. I don't see any difference between unmodified `rebase -i` and `rebase`, maybe you tested with different changes?

Comment: Maybe my question was bit too verbose. The question is: why the plain `git rebase` causes strange "file deleted" conflics, but `git rebase -i` does not. When using `rebase -i`, I just pick all the commits. So basically these two rebase commands should do exactly the same thing, but the other generates conflicts and the other does not.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda I edited the question, it was quite unclear, indeed.